# flutter text field underline and dropdown underline are not in the same line

Tags: flutter, dart, drop-down-menu, textfield, underline

[image]

hi, in flutter I have tow widgets TextFormField and DropdownButton in a Row But as you see in the picture they are not in the same line

```
Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              width: HDW().fullWidth(context: context, width: 0.35),
              height: HDW().fullHeight(context: context, height: 0.08),
              child: TextFormField(
                controller: sectionTextEditingController,
                onChanged: (n) {
                  homeController.setSectionNo(n);
                },
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: HDW().fullWidth(context: context, width: 0.35),
              height: HDW().fullHeight(context: context, height: 0.08),
              child:
              DropdownButton<String?>(
                items: homeController.sections
                    .map((e) => DropdownMenuItem<String?>(
                  value: e,
                  child: Text( e,textAlign: TextAlign.start,style: TextStyle(fontFamily: font),),
                ),)
                    .toList(),
                value: homeController.selectedLetter.isNotEmpty
                    ? homeController.selectedLetter
                    : null,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  homeController.setSectionLetter(value!);
                },
                hint: Text(
                  'تحديد',
                  style: TextStyle(fontFamily: font),
                ),
                isExpanded: true,
                icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
```

for note
double fullHeight({
required BuildContext context,
double height = 1,
}) =>
height * MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

Comment: Can you minimize the widget by removing other class(`HDW()`...)

Comment: dear yassin the class have methods for shorts like the one in the note, they are some thing for size etc, any way i will remove the un needed lines

Comment: the height depends on those value also you if it larger, you need to use `expands: true` for textFiled

Answer (score 1):

Setting `isDense: true` on `DropdownButton` will solve the bottom padding,

```dart
child: DropdownButton<String?>(
  isDense: true,
```

but when it large size, textFiled is needed to be

```dart
child: TextFormField(
  expands: true,
  maxLines: null,
  minLines: null,
```

Comment: still the same.

Comment: consider include full sample widget without having unnecessary and outside data. Find more about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)